# Tensorflow NN with specific custom cost function

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to make a neural network in tensorflow that doesn't really belong in the classification of regression categories. It's probably closer to reinforcement learning.

I've made a network with a few ReLU hidden layers that ends in a 3-element softmax output layer. The target vectors for each sample are rewards (can be negative for penalty or 0 for neutral) for making a certain choice (of which there are 3). The idea is to maximize the summed reward over all samples.

Given one sample input that is mapped to a model output M=[a,b,c] with targets Y=[d,e,f]; the loss for that specific sample would be M*Y', or simply -tf.matmul(model, Y, transpose_b=True). However when working with batches resulting in matrices in stead of vectors, I'm at a loss (heh) how to express this as a cost-function in a way that TensorFlow's optimizers can use. Simply using the example code above would yield a meaningless batchsize^2-sized matrix.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the output of your model for a mini-batch of `N` examples, call it `output`. That would have the shape `[N, 1, 3]`. (Note : Typically, output of softmax would have the shape `[N, 3]`, but you can use `tf.reshape` to reshape it to `[N, 1, 3]`). Call your rewards or targets `target`, and that would also have the shape `[N, 1, 3]`. You can do the following operation to get the `loss` with shape `[N, 1, 1]` :

```
loss = tf.batch_matmul(output, tf.transpose(target, [0, 2, 1]))
```

If you want to average loss for your minibatch, you can do the following :

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

in which case you get a scalar value.